# How to read stream+json responses from Vuejs?

Tags: json, rest, vue.js, axios

I use axios http client in vuejs application and this code:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8081/pets')
    .then(response => {
      this.pets = response.data;
    })
```

If server return simple "application/json" conten, then all fine.
But i want read "application/stream+json" for each row separately.

For example:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8081/pets')
    .then(response => {
      this.pets.push(response.data)
    })
```

But this code (as expected) does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem with SSE:

```
let es = new EventSource('http://localhost:8081/pets');
es.addEventListener('message', event => {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    this.pets.push(data);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got your mean correctly or not! but I gave data and use it as separately.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8081/pets')
    .then(response => {
      for(var key in response.data) {
         this.pets.push(response.data[key]);  //row by row
      }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case there is a need to wait until the server forms the request completely. But i want read data in stream (as ready), row by row.

Comment: You should call the api intervally so send request to api back to back until state of api is completed results and push dara for each api call, second way is use the socket io.